# NSMutableDictionary and NSArray

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

I am splitting a String:

```
@"Sam|26|Developer,Hannah|22|Team Leader,Max|1|Dog"
```

and using NSMutableDictionary to display in a TableViewCell with 3 labels. Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

NSString *test = @"Sam Parrish|26|Developer,Hannah Rajamets|22|Team Leader,Max Parrish|1|Dog";

testArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
testArray = [test componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (NSString *s in testArray) {

        testArrayNew = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
        [dict setObject:[testArrayNew objectAtIndex:1] forKey:[testArrayNew objectAtIndex:0]];
        [dict setObject:[testArrayNew objectAtIndex:2] forKey:[testArrayNew objectAtIndex:1]];

        NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", [dict description]);
    }

[dict retain];

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[dict allKeys] count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    untitled *cell = (untitled *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"untitled" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = (untitled *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.nameLabel.text = [[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.ageLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:cell.nameLabel.text];
    cell.jobLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:cell.ageLabel.text];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

this is displaying 6 TableViewCells when I run, 3 of which are perfect, the other 3 are an assortment of the data. i realise this is to do with the `setObject: forKey:` but can't seem to find the solution for this to work correctly.

any help much appreciated..

sam

Comment: Where you are creating the *testArray*?

Comment: sorry i missed that bit out when cut&pasting - its there now

Comment: Your way of setting keys to dictionary is surprising me. :-) Why do you use this way? Is there any specific reason for you to do like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store the data as an NSArray holding NSArrays....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NSString *test = @"Sam Parrish|26|Developer,Hannah Rajamets|22|Team Leader,Max Parrish|1|Dog";

        data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (NSString *s in testArray) {
            [data addObject:[s componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"]];
        }
}
```

Then in

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

use

```
// Configure the cell.
NSArray *cellData = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.nameLabel.text = [cellData objectAtIndex:0];
cell.ageLabel.text = [cellData objectAtIndex:1];
cell.jobLabel.text = [cellData objectAtIndex:2];
```

Comment: data is an NSMutableArray btw.

Comment: Do you have data in the array and child arrays.... there is no reason why that code won't work, and it IS the correct way to handle what you want to do.

Comment: ahhh you also need - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [data count];
}

Comment: BTW, that is THE best comment I have seen on SO to date. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're saying that the first three cells are correct and the other three shouldn't be shown at all?  If that's the case, the problem is this:

```
return [[dict allKeys] count];
```

Shouldn't it be...

```
return [testArray count];
```

...in which case, you need to retain `testArray`.

In addition, you have a memory leak.  You create an instance of `NSArray`, then you immediately leak it by assigning the return value of `componentsSeparatedByString:` to the same variable.  Have you run the static analyser over your code?

Comment: its not the first 3 cells that are correct, they are in a random order, and the correct cells are placed 3rd, 4th and 5th. Like i said i think its because of the setObject: and forKey: code as i appear to be setting a key to an object which is why it creates more cells

Comment: can a NSMutableDictionary show like this ... Sam => 26 => developer ?

Comment: as at the moment it does... 1 = Dog;
    22 = "Team Leader";
    26 = Developer;
    "Hannah Rajamets" = 22;
    "Max Parrish" = 1;
    "Sam Parrish" = 26;